# Firebase to own server

Tags: firebase, server, backend

I am an IOS developer and I want to use Firebase for the start of my project. However, as far as I know, firebase locks you with its own ecosystem. Is there a way to replace firebase with my own server in the future?

I searched but I couldn’t find any source.

Comment: Firebase is a fully hosted service.  There is no self-hosting and there is no source code for the backend components.  You can use the emulator to build locally, but that is not appropriate for use in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase is a proprietary platform which provides a set of backend cloud computing services and application development platforms. Therefore, the corresponding infrastructure is always hosted on the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) and it's not possible to host the Firebase platform on your own.

If you want to host such a platform on your own, I would recommend a similar Open Source projects such as [Supabase](https://supabase.com/), which provides equivalent features. You can either host it on your own (e.g. via a [Docker image](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/self-hosting/docker)) or use their free/paid [cloud offer](https://supabase.com/pricing).

Comment: Okey thanks a lot my friend ı searched and decided to use Supabase.